# pub install -> HttpParserException: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: installation, dart, dart-pub

Trying to install a simple app with one dependency yields an error

```
Pub install fail, Resolving dependencies...
Downloading html5lib 0.0.12 from hosted...
HttpParserException: Connection closed before full header was received
```

Comment: Are you seeing this error from within the editor ?, if so then try to restart the editor (this has fixed seemlier issues for me).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a transient bug. If it still happening, please open a bug at dartbug.com/new with specifics about your OS, version of Dart, and running pub --verbose. Thanks!