# resolving dependencies with pub get failed

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

I tried to install the dependencies for the [polymer-dart-blog](https://github.com/sdeleuze/polymer-dart-blog) with 'pub get' but unfortunately this operation failed. I have absolutely no idea what the problem is. The ouput looks like this:

```
C:\Users\fraherm\workspace\polymer-dart-blog>pub get
Resolving dependencies..........................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................Error in PubHttp
Client.send (issue 12581) error: HttpException: Connection closed before full he
ader was received, uri = https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/unittest/versions
/0.8.10%2B3
stacktrace: #0      PubHttpClient.send (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor
-win-stable/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/http.dart:60)
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed.<anonymous closure> (package:http/src/base_cl
ient.dart:118)
#2      _Future._propagateToListeners.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_imp
l.dart:453)
#3      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:683)
#4      _RootZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:823)
#5      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:445)
#6      _Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:303)
#7      _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:
354)
#8      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:18)
#9      _createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:11)
#10     _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:151)
#11     _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (timer_impl.dart:166)
#12     _RawReceivePortImpl._handler (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:1)
#13     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dar
t:93)

Connection closed before full header was received
```

Comment: Is this the first time you use pub get or did it already work earlier i.e. for another project?

Comment: That is the first time I use pub get. I thought it is a good idea to learn from an existing project so i cloned the polymer-dart-blog and tried to install the dependencies.

Comment: Yes that is just fine, but it's important to know if this might be a generic or a project specific problem. Do you access the web using a proxy server?

Comment: No, I don't use any proxy. Also pinging pub.dartlang.org works for me just fine.

Comment: And you get each time the same error message?

Comment: Yes. I tested 'pub get' with another project and it works. Seems like the problem is project related.

Comment: I removed the git address for start from pubspec.yaml and it works now. =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may just wait a while and then try again as
Seth explains in [pub install -> HttpParserException: Connection closed before full header was received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958709/pub-install-httpparserexception-connection-closed-before-full-header-was-rec)
Seems to be a problem with the server.